# How do I change the name of an existing event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In Windows Forms, if you change the method name (for example, `button1_Click`) to something else, it doesn't work any more.

I find this strange because in a console application, as far as I remember, you could name the methods as you wished. I'm trying to understanding what's happening.

**How can I change the name of these methods** (such as `button1_Click`)?

Comment: Your original question was about learning material, I have edited it to leave only your concrete question. If you need help with anything else, don't hesitate to ask. By the way, if you still want some learning material, I can suggest you to try the book [Windows Forms Programming in C#](http://amzn.to/19kXegK) by Chris Sells, published by Addison-Wesley Professional.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Renaming eventhandlers WORK. You have failed your Perception rolls many times in a row. (1) in your IDE there's probably an option called Refactor/Rename that would do that properly, (2) when renaming manually, in your IDE there's probably "Find All References" that would show you all the places to change, (3)if not, then surely there's "Find text in files", (4)the Designer and Properties doesn't allow you to rename. You 'select' the name from the list, or if does not exist, NEW is added, (5)when you tried renaming and NEW handler was created and you didn't notice that old one still sits there

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*This questions is about the case where renaming a method causes the forms designer to stop working. Although I have covered (all that I can think of) how events works in general.*

---

### What happened?

What you experience is an artifact of the forms designer.

Sure, you can have any method name you want, the matter is the forms designer is binding those methods to events behind the scenes, if you change the method name after the forms designer has linked it to the event it will no longer work (it can't find the method).

---

### Giving proper names to your event handlers

In Visual Studio, look at the properties of the object you want to bind an event to, and then select events (on the top of the panel):

[image: Open the events tab of the properties panel]

There you will see a list the available events and you will be able to bind an existing method or type the name for a new one:

[image: Select of create a new method to bind]

---

### If I have already screwed, how do I fix it?

If your designer is not appearing because of this you will have to edit the code file that is generated by the designer. The file generated by the designer has the name of the form followed by `.Designer.cs` (for example: `Form1.Designer.cs`), you can find it with your solution explorer:

[image: Find the code file generated by the designer]

*Note*: You may have to expand the sub-tree created on your form to reveal the file.

There you will find a line that looks something like this:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

And Visual Studio will tell you that `button1_Click` is not defined. You can edit there the name of the method to the new name, or remove the line to have the designer work again, and bind a new method.

---

### Renaming an existing method without the hassle

You can summon the Rename dialog. This can be done by several ways:

- From the Menus: `Edit` -> `Refactor` -> `Rename`
- By contextual Menu on the name of the Method:  `Refactor` -> `Rename`
- Put the cursor on the Method name and type `Alt + Shift + F10` and then select `Rename`
- Put the cursor on the Method name and press `F2`

*Note*: You can customise your Visual Studio, the above menus and keyboard shortcuts may be changed.

The Rename dialog looks like this:

[image: Use the Rename dialog]

There you can type a new name for the method, and by doing so any reference or call to that method withing the loaded projects will be changed too. That includes the code generated by the Forms Designer.

---

### Binding an event handler by hand

All that the forms designer does is present a UI that facilitates editing the form and write code on your behalf. Don't let it fool you into thinking that you can't write code yourself.

In fact, you can create your own methods and even bind them to the events of your Form. I have been saying "bind" because it is easier to understand at this level, although the accepted lingo is **subscribe**. So what we are going to do, is create a button and *subscribe* to its `Click` event.

First let's take a look at the class of your form, it looks something like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice it says `partial`, that means that there could be more code for this class in another file, in fact that is the file `Form1.Designer.cs` where the forms designer has been adding code.

Second notice it calls a method `InitializeComponent` inside the constructor of the form. This method has been created by the forms designer and it takes responsibility of initializing all the controls and components you have added using the forms designer (hence the name of the method).

Now, let's say we want to add a button without the forms designer we can do it like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button myButton;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a new Button
            myButton = new Button();

            // Set the properties of the Button
            myButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 12);
            myButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
            myButton.Text = "My Button";

            // Add the Button to the form
            this.Controls.Add(myButton);
        }
    }
}
```

We have created a private field named `myButton` of type `Button` that will hold the new button. Then inside the constructor we add some new lines to create a new `Button` and assign it to `myButton` and give it position (`Location`), `Size` and `Text`. And finally we have added the newly created button to the `Controls` of the form.

Now we want to add an event handler for the Click event on this new button. Remember that this button is not in the forms designer, we we are going to have to do it "by hand".

In order to do so, add the new method (you can named whatever you want):

```
        private void WhenClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Code */
        }
```

And then add it as an event handler for the Click event of the button (inside the constructor):

```
            // Add an event handler
            myButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(WhenClick);
```

Notice we are not calling `WhenClick`. instead we are making a reference to it.

Then we are creating a new `Delegate` of type `System.EventHandler` that will wrap the reference to the method `WhenClick`. I suggest to learn about [Using Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172(v=vs.90).aspx).

I repeat: we are not calling `WhenClick`. If we were to call `WhenClick` we would do something like this: `WhenClick(param1, param2)`. Please note that this is not what we are doing here, we haven't added parenthesis `(/*...*/)` after the method name, so we are not doing a method call.

---

You can also use some syntactic sugar to make all this easier:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a new Button and set its properties
            myButton = new Button()
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 12),
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23),
                Text = "My Button"
            };


            // Add the Button to the form
            this.Controls.Add(myButton);

            // Add an event handler (the compiler infers the delegate type)
            myButton.Click += WhenClick;
        }
```

You can even make the event handler an anonymous method:

```
            // Add an event handler (the compiler infers the delegate type)
            myButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                /* code */
            };
```

What you see here is a [C# Lambda expression](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLambda.aspx) (more info at MSDN [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)). Get used to these syntax, because you will see them more and more often.

---

### Understanding events

You have already seen code like this:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

As I told you we are passing a delegate object that has a reference to `button1_Click`. But that's not all that happens here... we are also giving it to `Click`.

Let's recapitulate and see how delegates behave. You can think about a delegate like an object that holds a method, or a pointer to a function if you prefer.

To understand this, I'll present some *examples* you can run as console applications. The first one shows that you can change the method that a delegate points to during runtime:

```
// Console Application Example #1 ;)
static void Main()
{
    Func<int, int> myfunc = null;

    myfunc = Add2;
    Console.WriteLine(myfunc(7)); // This prints 9
    myfunc = MultBy2;
    Console.WriteLine(myfunc(7)); // This prints 14
}

static int Add2(int x)
{
    // This method adds 2 to its input
    return x + 2;
}

static int MultBy2(int x)
{
    // This method  multiplies its input by 2
    return x * 2;
}
```

Notice `myfunc` is typed as `Func<int, int>` this is a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) delegate type that takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

Also notice that when I say `myfunc = Add2;`, it is not calling `Add2` (there are no parenthesis there), it is passing a reference of the method itself. the same is true for `myfunc = MultBy2;`: it is not calling `MultBy2`, we are passing it.

Using anonymous methods via lambda expressions you can write equivalent code is less lines:

```
// Console Application Example #1 ;)
static void Main()
{
    Func<int, int> myfunc = null;

    // This anonymous method adds 2 to its input
    myfunc = x => x + 2;
    Console.WriteLine(myfunc(7)); // This prints 9

    // This anonymous method  multiplies its input by 2
    myfunc = x => x * 2;
    Console.WriteLine(myfunc(7)); // This prints 14
}
```

Notice that we have two anonymous methods here: `x => x + 2` and `x => x * 2`. The first one (`x => x + 2`) is equivalent to the method `Add2` we had before, and the second one (`x => x * 2`) is equivalent to the method `MultBy2` we had before.

In this example I want you to see that the same delegate can point to different methods along the time. This is accomplished by having a *variable* that points to the methods!

---

For the second example, I'll present the "callback" pattern. That is a common pattern in which you pass a delegate as a "callback", that is: something that will be called "back to you" from the code you are calling:

```
// Console Application Example #2 ;)
static void Main()
{
    Func<int, bool> filter = IsPair;
    // An array with numbers
    var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 45, 99};
    PrintFiltered(array, filter);
}

static bool IsPair(int x)
{
    // True for pair numbers
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

static void PrintFiltered(int[] array, Func<int, bool> filter)
{
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (filter== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filter");
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (filter(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
4
8
```

In this code we are having a *variable* `filter` that points to the method `IsPair`. I'll repeat this again and and again: in the line `Func<int, bool> filter = IsPair;` we are not calling the method `IsPair`, instead we are taking a reference to it.

Of course, it is possible to do the same without declaring the `filter` *variable*, you can pass the method reference directly:

```
// Console Application Example #2 ;)
static void Main()
{
    // An array with numbers
    var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 45, 99};
    PrintFiltered(array, IsPair); //<---
}

static bool IsPair(int x)
{
    // True for pair numbers
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

static void PrintFiltered(int[] array, Func<int, bool> filter)
{
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (filter== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filter");
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (filter(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot stress this hard enough: When I say `PrintFiltered(array, IsPair);` it is not calling `IsPair`, it is passing it as a parameter to `PrintFiltered`. Here effectively you have a method (`PrintFiltered`) that can take a reference to another method (`IsPair`) as a reference.

Of course you can write the same code using an anonymous method that replaces `IsPair`:

```
// Console Application Example #2 ;)
static void Main()
{
    // An array with numbers
    var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 45, 99};
    PrintFiltered(array, x => x % 2 == 0);
}

static void PrintFiltered(int[] array, Func<int, bool> filter)
{
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (filter== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filter");
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (filter(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
4
8
```

In this example `x => x % 2 == 0` is an anonymous method that is equivalent to the method `IsPair` we had before.

We have successfully filtered the array to only show the numbers that are pair. You can easily reuse the same code for a different filter. For example, the following line can be used to output only the items in the array that are less than 10:

```
    PrintFiltered(array, x => x < 10);
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
7
8
9
```

With this example I want to show you that you can take advantage of the delegates to improve the reusability of your code, by having parts that change depending on the delegate you pass.

---

Now that - hopefully - we understand this, it is not hard to think that you could have a list of Delegate objects, and call them in succession:

```
// Console Application Example #3 ;)
static void Main()
{
    // List<Action<int>> is a List that stores objects of Type Action<int>
    // Action<int> is a Delegate that represents methods that
    //  takes an int but does not return (example: void func(int val){/*code*/})
    var myDelegates = new List<Action<int>>();

    // We add delegates to the list
    myDelegates.Add(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    myDelegates.Add(x => Console.WriteLine(x + 5));

    // And we call them in succesion
    foreach (var item in myDelegates)
    {
        item(74);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
74
79
```

You can see both anonymous methods (`x => Console.WriteLine(x)` and `Console.WriteLine(x + 5)`) has been called, one after the other... this happens inside the `foreach` loop.

Now, we can accomplish similar results with a multicast delegate:

```
// Console Application Example #3 ;)
static void Main()
{
    // This is a delegate... we haven't give it a method to point to:
    Action<int> myDelegates = null;

    // We add methods to it
    myDelegates += x => Console.WriteLine(x);
    myDelegates += x => Console.WriteLine(x + 5);

    // And we call them in succession
    if (myDelegates != null) // Will be null if we don't add methods
    {
        myDelegates(74);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
74
79
```

Again, both anonymous methods has been called. And this is exactly how events work. The default implementation of an event uses a multicast delegated wrapped inside. Custom implementation of an event may use a list or similar structure to hold the delegates.

Now, if the event is just a list of delegates... that means the event is keeping a reference to all the methods it wants to call. And it also means that you *could* remove delegates from the list (or add more than one).

If you want to **unsubscribe** or unbind from an event, you can do so like this:

```
this.button1.Click -= button1_Click;
```

For a delegate object to an anonymous method it is a little bit more complicated, because you will need to keep the delegate in a variable to able to pass it back for removal:

```
Action<int> myDelegates = null;

// Create the delegate
var myDelegate = x => Console.WriteLine(x);

// Add the delegate
myDelegates += myDelegate;

// ...

// Remove the delegate
myDelegates -= myDelegate;
```

---

### Did you say *custom implementation* of an event?

Does that means you can create your own events? Yes, and yes. If you want to publish an event in one of your classes you can declare it just like any other member.

This is an example that uses a multicast delegate:

```
// Event declaration:
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

// Method to raise the event (aka event dispatcher):
priavet void Raise_MyEvent()
{
    var myEvent = MyEvent;
    if (myEvent != null)
    {
        var e = new EventArgs();
        myEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

For a custom implementation take this example:

```
// List to hold the event handlers:
List<EventHandler> myEventHandlers = new List<EventHandler>();

// Event declaration:
event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        lock (myEventHandlers)
        {
            myEventHandlers.Add(value);
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (myEventHandlers)
        {
            myEventHandlers.Remove(value);
        }
    }
}

// Method to raise the event (aka event dispatcher):
private void Raise_MyEvent()
{
    var e = new EventArgs();
    foreach (var item in myEventHandlers)
    {
        item(this, e);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this not hard to read, now that you know how events work. The only details should be [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), it is there because `List` is not thread-safe. You could also use a thread-safe data structure or a different locking mechanism, I kept this one for simplicity.

Even if you don't write your own events, there are a few things to learn from here:

1. Event handlers execute consecutively (by default), so it is good idea that event handlers execute fast (maybe defer to asynchronous operations for the hard work) to prevent "clogging" the event dispatcher.
2. The event dispatcher usually don't handle exceptions (it can be done), so it is good idea to avoid throwing excepting in event handlers.
3. The "publisher" of the event is keeping a list of the event handlers, it is a good idea to unsubscribe when you don't need need the event handler anymore.

---

*Notes*:

While looking for example I found the series of articles "Delegates in C# - Attempt to Look Inside" by Ed Guzman ([Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113297/Delegates-in-C-Attempt-to-Look-Inside-Part-1), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115377/Delegates-in-C-Attempt-to-Look-Inside-Part-2), [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115710/Delegates-in-C-Attempt-to-Look-Inside-Part-3) and [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117611/Delegates-in-C-Attempt-to-look-inside-Part-4)) very easy to read - although a bit outdated - you should check them out. You may want to read the [Evolution of Anonymous Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) in C# for a grasp of what's missing.

Some commonly used Delegate Types built-in in .NET include:

- Generic

  - `Action<*>` (that is: `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` ...)
  - `Func<*, TResult>` (that is: `Func<T, TResult>`, `Func<T1, T2, TResult>`  ...)
  - `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`
  - `Comparison<T>`
  - `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`
- Non Generic

  - `Action`
  - `Predicate`
  - `EventHandler`
  - `ThreadStart`
  - `ParametrizedThreadStart`

You may be interested in [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).

Threading and thread-safety it a even broader topic than delegates and events, don't rush to understand it all.

If you want play along with Lambda Expression and C# in general, I suggest to get a copy of [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). This make reduce the hassle of creating new project to test things.

Comment: Wow.. My intuition was alerting me that in fact that since changing the method name would give an error, then the method had to be defined previously elsewhere.

Comment: This brings another question.. how does C# distinguishes when you are creating a method and when are you calling it? Because in the console app mode the exact same sentence was used to create a method, and we used to call it as NameOfTheMethod(Arguments); this apparently doesn't happen in winforms.

Comment: @CésarAmorim you declare and define (there is no distinction in C#) the method as a member of a class such as `int Method(string arg){/*body*/}` this is true even in WinForms, maybe the confusion is because the forms designer is doing it for you. You call the method like this `var val = Method("argument");` and you can pass it as an object like this `Something(Method);` So notice that when I refer to the method without calling it I don't put `()` after the method name. You maybe interested in learning about [Using Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @CésarAmorim I have extended my answer to include how you can add an event handler without the forms designer. I hope this helps to understand what's going on. I have also presented some syntax that may look confusing, make sure to check the linked material.

Comment: Didn't you mean object.Method(argument) instead of Something(Method); ? I've never seen that construction.

Comment: @CésarAmorim If `Something` is a method (of the current object / class) that takes a delegate and `Method` is another method compatible with the delegate type, then `Somethng(Method);` is valid construct. I was trying to get that point across: you can refer to the method without calling it. So in: `Somethng(Method);` you pass the method, and in `Somethng(Method());` you call the method and pass whatever it returns.

Comment: @CésarAmorim I strongly believe that the best way to learn this is to run the code (perhaps in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)) and have it work right in front of you. Using a full IDE and going step by step is also highly recommended. Watch the video [How Do I: Step with The Debugger in Visual Studio?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee672313.aspx) to learn how to do step by step debugging in Visual Studio. So, I want to encorage you to try the "Console Application Examples" I have provided you. Just tell me if you run into any problems during that.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course change the name of your event. It just sounds like you don't know about the designer file :)

The designer file is just the result of your UI design, and if you don't update the name of your event in the UI it does not compile :)

Comment: sorry, i noticed now that this is offtopic, someone can close the topic please?